Rsync fails with permission error while executed through rundeck, works fine otherwise
I am trying execute a rsync command using rundeck on two local folders:
rsync -avur -n /tmp/rundeck/test_1/ /tmp/rundeck/test_2/

However, this gives me below error:
sending incremental file list
rsync: change_dir "/tmp/rundeck/test_1" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/tmp/rundeck/test_2/": Permission denied (13)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(641) [Receiver=3.1.3]
Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 3

The permissions of these folders are as below and owned by the user executing the rsync command that is rundeck.
[root@host~]# ls -al /tmp/rundeck/test_*
/tmp/rundeck/test_1:
total 380
drwxr-xr-x.    2 rundeck rundeck      6 May 27 19:51 .
drwxrwxrwx. 6361 rundeck rundeck 211290 May 27 19:55 ..

/tmp/rundeck/test_2:
total 380
drwxr-xr-x.    2 rundeck rundeck      6 May 27 19:51 .
drwxrwxrwx. 6361 rundeck rundeck 211290 May 27 19:55 ..

The above command executed directly in the shell with above user works fine:
su rundeck
bash-4.4$ rsync -avur -n /tmp/rundeck/test_1/ /tmp/rundeck/test_2/
sending incremental file list
./

sent 64 bytes  received 19 bytes  166.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)

I am not sure what's the issue here, and why it fails with rundeck?

Make sure that SELinux isn't blocking the /tmp folder for writing/exec.
